# Accessing Flurry User ID

Tags: ios, flurry

I know that there's a setUserID method in Flurry, but how would I get the user ID that Flurry sets by default for a device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flurry uses SHA1 Mac for iOS and Android ID for Android apps as device identifiers. These are used solely for internal identification purpose, and are not disclosed to developers. You need to use setUserID method to assign a unique user ID for a user in your app. Please be sure not to use this method to pass any private or confidential information about the user.

(Full disclosure: I work at Flurry)